# Resize a very tiny xcf image without blurring or dithering it

Tags: image-manipulation, imagemagick, images

I have some drawings I made with an Intuos tablet. All of these drawings are 25x35 or so. The color of each pixel was very carefully selected. They're kind of like 'miniatures.'

I need to resize these. But I ran into problems. The images get dithered, and if I make them huge, blurred.

Here is the image at normal size. It happens to be dithered, but this is not visible.

[image]

I used the following two imagemagic commands, but they both produced blurring:

```
convert -resize 400% image.xcf image-2.jpg
convert -adaptive-resize 400% image.xcf image-2.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are *many* more [resize options](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) in imagemagick. `-scale` looks like what you need.

[image]

Also, do not use JPEG for pixel-perfect "miniatures"; use PNG instead (or if impossible, GIF). JPEG is designed for photos and uses lossy compression, resulting in distortion clearly noticeable after scaling your provided JPEG sample.

This article on [image scaling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) might be interesting.